# Understanding Sharepoint Architecture to adopt them in a custom developed CMS

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to undertand the architectural concepts around how

- Security model and user authorization
- Revisioning
- Content localization
  etc.. are implemented in Sharepoint, in order to see if I could adopt those concepts in a CMS project that I'm currently working on.

Could someone direct me on any useful resources, tutorials, books etc.. on this?

doesn't necesssarily need to be sharepoint, as long as the material covers the basic CMS concepts from an architectural perspective.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Google might know a thing or two ;)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find few links provided below which will answer your queries for SharePoint 2010

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457529.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/introduction-to-versioning-HA010021576.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/05/view-changes-makes-in-browser-content-localization-easier.aspx